# Как убрать изменение размера и чтобы объект был статичен

Tags: html, css

Код

```css
body{
 margin: 0;
}
.content-header {
 font-family: "Roboto";
 font-weight: 300;
 color: #777;
 background-color: #eee;
 padding: 10px;
 padding-left: 0;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -3px 10px gray;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 10px gray;
 position: relative;


}
.content-header ul li{
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
 padding: 10px;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin-left: 10px;
}

.content-header ul{
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Duoxx on Github</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-header">
      <ul>
        <li class="content-logo"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tXAe.jpg?s=328&g=1" alt="duoxx" width="40"></li>

        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Switch language</li>



      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrapper"></div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Мне нужно чтобы картинка не изменяла размер навбара и при этом оставалась статичной.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не понял, что значит оставалась статичной? Не двигалась с места? Если да то через позишн. Либо через изменение размера.

Тут придётся применить margin-left на ширину картинки плюс отступ от нее.

```
.content-logo{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 10px;
} 
.content-logo img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: -10px;
}
```